# Is it possible to publish asp.net web api in a different port in Visual Studio 2015 ? IIS not IIS Express

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2015, iis-7

My goal is to publish web api in IIS. I will call this web API from android application. I'm using IIS not IIS Express and xamarin in visual studio 2015.
I'm very confused that IIS express comes with a port no in project properties
(http://localhost:57811/). If I change it to IIS, I no longer able to specify a port number (both in 2012 and 2015).

So I check "Override application root URL" and have put port no in it. After publish my web api not listening to the port no I mention, Instead its looking at default port no. Can anybody explain how this is happening ?

Comment: You need to create virtual directory in IIS to achieve this.

Comment: In IIS, you add a binding to the site with any available port you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an available port by going into IIS, drilling down on your ServerName, Sites, right clicking on your SiteName (Default is: Default Web Site) and selecting "Edit Bindings...".

When you are at the "Site Bindings" menu you can click "Add..." and then chose the type and the Port Number.

[Edit Bindings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAefw.jpg)